# Android: xml content clear with adding DrawerLayout

Tags: android-toolbar, drawerlayout

I have a layout contain:toolbar , DrawerLayout for sliding menu, a viewpager and a tablayout. Without adding DrawerLayout my program work correctly. When i add DrawerLayout the application just shows toolbar with Drawerlayout.
Here is my activit_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.prj.shopt.MainActivity">
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:title=""
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:background="#ffffff">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            tools:openDrawer="start"
            >
            <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:id="@+id/nav_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
                app:menu="@menu/menu_sliding"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@color/tab_active"/>
    <CustomViews.CustomViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/tabsViewPager"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/tab_active"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/CustomTabTextStyle"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@null"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_inactive"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where is my wrong?